# Increase time by an hour before comparing

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have code containing time in the military format.

```
<div class="em" data-time="17:30">
```

I am comparing that time to the current time to determine if the set time has passed or not.

```
var curDate = new Date(),
    curTime = curDate.getTime(),
    givenTm = $(this).find('.em').attr('data-time'),
    givenMs = Date.parse(curDate.toDateString() + ' ' + givenTm);

if (curTime > givenMs) {
   // time has passed
}
```

I need to modify my code to check not against the time in data attribute, but an hour after that given time. Also my given time can only be on the same day and no later then 23:30, which means I only care if the given time is no later then 23:00.

How do I put all this together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust by an hour, just add one hour in milliseconds (60 * 60 * 1000) to the comparison.  To ignore any given time after 2300, you'll need to add another clause into the conditional.  So something like this might do it:

```
if (new Date(givenMs).getHours() < 23
    && curTime > givenMs + 3600000) {
    // time has passed
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.toJSON` , `String.prototype.replace()` , `String.prototype.slice()`

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  var curDate = new Date(),
    curTime = curDate.toJSON(),
    givenTm = $(this).find(".em").attr("data-time")
    .replace(/(\d+)(?=:)/, function(match) {
      return Number(match) + 1
    }),
    curr = curTime.slice(11, -8).replace(":", ""),
    given = givenTm.replace(":", "");   

  if (curr < 2330 && given < 2330) {
    // time has passed
    console.log("currTime:", curr, "givenTime:", given,
      "time has not passed")
  } else {
    console.log("time has passed")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div>click
  <div class="em" data-time="17:30">
  </div>
```